# Looking to make shortcut or invisible batch to run partial filename of a program

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, shortcuts

I'm looking to make a shortcut to a program on a network drive where the program and it's name is sometimes updated to a new version. Right now it's located at and named to this.

\\USERZ390\e\Benching\GPU-Z.2.22.0.exe

But periodically the program is updated to something like GPU-Z.2.23.0.exe or GPU-Z.3.1.0.exe, etc. Basically, GPU-Z.*.exe

Is there a way to make a shortcut to this program that accepts wildcards? If not, what about a batch file that runs invisibly (no visible command prompt) without needing to install extra apps?

Thanks in advance, you guys are awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Create a shortcut with the command line like

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c for /f %x in ('dir /b \\USERZ390\e\Benching\GPU-Z.*.exe') do \\USERZ390\e\Benching\%x
```

If there exists 2 or more executables in this folder that matched a template all of them will be started.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to want to wait for GPU-Z program to close before the command prompt terminates itself. Any way to make it so cmd prompt DOESNT show? Otherwise works great.

Comment: Add `start`... with hidden cmd option maybe.